# React Hooks state update applies only once when called from callbacks in an array of components

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, callback

I'm having trouble to lift the state up in that case:
I have a button which on each click adds element to 'mylist' through 'setMyList'. These elements are 'Child' components (the div className "site" is just a CSS square), and I want that each time I click on one of those components/elements it increments 'count' thanks to 'setCount' in the callback that is given to the 'Child' component in 'setMyList'.
But what happen is that, for instance, I create a square then click on it, 'count' doesn't go further than 1, then with another square created, clicking on it makes 'count' goes up to 2 but not more, and so on.
And when I click back on the first square 'count' is 1, it looks like the state is saved for each 'Child' components instead of incrementing it.

Here are my components:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Child from './Child.js'

function Parent() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [mylist, setMyList] = useState([])

    function increment() {
        console.log("TEST")
        setCount(count + 1)
    }
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => setMyList([...mylist, <Child onClick={increment}></Child>])}> </button>
        <h2>count {count}</h2>
        {mylist}
        (count should be updated from child)
      </div>
    );
  }
  
export default Parent
```

Note that each time a square is clicked on, It does go in 'increment' function because the console log displays, but it goes through setCount withtout doing anything.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import "./Site.css"

function Child(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="Site" onClick={props.onClick}></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setCount((count) => count + 1)`;

This will ensure that `setCount` can **get the latest count value** every time.

This is because every time you push `Child`, the `increment` function will be recreated, and then the `count` in the `increment` function is actually **the value when the `increment` function was `created`**.

In addition, you can use `React.useCallback` to optimize this.

```
const increment = React.useCallback(() => {
  setCount((count) => count + 1);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you it works ! I just have two more questions if you don't mind, why this syntax of setCount ensure to get the latest ? And why it recreates the increment function on each pushes ?

Comment: The `Parent` function is re-executed for each rendering, which forms a [JavaScript closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). When you pass a function to `setCount`, `React` will call the function with the latest `count`. For more: [Funtional-Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)